# Trying to restore glacier deep archive to s3, but unable to do so with mfa

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I want to restore glacier deep archive folder, I do have aws MFA enabled so when I try to run the below command getting the below error:

aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket MYBUCKET --query "Contents[?StorageClass=='GLACIER']" --output text | awk '{print substr($0, index($0, $2))}' | awk '{NF-=3};3' > glacier-restore.txt --profile xxx

error : awk: fatal: cannot open file `--profile' for reading (No such file or directory)
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

Answer (score 1):

The `--profile xxx` is not an argument of the `aws` command.

Try:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --profile xxx --bucket MYBUCKET --query "Contents[?StorageClass=='GLACIER']" --output text | awk '{print substr($0, index($0, $2))}' | awk '{NF-=3};3' > glacier-restore.txt
```